# How to make a USB device multi-touch enabled?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I'm making my first USB device driver for Linux, and I'm trying to connect a touch panel device.

I have tried this device in Win7, using Win7's default touch panel driver.
Using a line monitor/reader, I was able to get the raw data with multi-touch **ENABLED**.
Let's just say for sample's sake a multi-touch data header is **[0x8301]** and **[0x8701]**
for the first and second touch respectively.

Now with multi-touch **DISABLED** the raw data header would be **[0x8101]**

Now with the driver I made for Linux, I can only get it to output **[0x8101]**, which is a one touch data header.

So I'm guessing somewhere in this part of the initialization code, I have to say to the device it is a multi-touch device. Or I'm probably initializing it wrongly.

```
    struct input_dev *input_dev;
input_dev = input_allocate_device();
input_dev->name = usb_mtouch->name;
input_dev->phys = usb_mtouch->phys;
usb_to_input_id(usb_mtouch->udev, &input_dev->id);
input_dev->dev.parent = &interface->dev;

input_set_drvdata(input_dev, usb_mtouch);

input_dev->open = mtouchdrv_open;
input_dev->close = mtouchdrv_close;

input_dev->evbit[0] |= BIT_MASK(EV_KEY) | BIT_MASK(EV_ABS);
input_dev->keybit[BIT_WORD(BTN_DIGI)] |= BIT_MASK(BTN_TOOL_PEN) |
    BIT_MASK(BTN_TOUCH) | BIT_MASK(BTN_STYLUS);
input_set_abs_params(input_dev, ABS_X, usb_mtouch->x_min, usb_mtouch->x_max, 0, 0);
input_set_abs_params(input_dev, ABS_Y, usb_mtouch->y_min, usb_mtouch->y_max, 0, 0);
input_set_abs_params(input_dev, ABS_PRESSURE, 0, usb_mtouch->press_max, 0, 0);
input_dev->absbit[BIT_WORD(ABS_MISC)] |= BIT_MASK(ABS_MISC);
```

Also, I am using Linux 2.6.24.

Thanks!

Naze

Comment: It doesn't work with either of the `synaptics` or `wacom` drivers?

Comment: Does your kernel support it? ( http://lii-enac.fr/en/architecture/linux-input/multitouch-howto.html#hid-multitouch )

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams, how do i get it to use the wacom driver? by the way, this is an ARM9 embedded system.

Comment: @vines: thanks for the link, i'll try this one out too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it. You would have to send a control message to the device.

```
int usb_control_msg(struct usb_device *dev, unsigned int pipe, __u8 request,
                     __u8 requesttype, __u16 value, __u16 index, void *data,
                     __u16 size, int timeout)
```

Most devices are one-touched enabled by default. So sending a message to the device will do the trick.

The tricky part is what message to send. Since Win7 can make it one-touch or multi-touch. What I did was just compare the the Initialization Sequence on both. And apply the "missing" messages on Linux.